# how i get multipe sku value in pixel tacking link

Tags: magento2, link, pixel-tracking

i am implement the pixel tracking link and i found the this url

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="https://insight.adsrvr.org/track/pxl/?adv=qvrd1lp&ct=0:fn55yrx&fmt=3&td1={{ADD TRASACTION REVENUE}}&td2={{ADD Transaction Id}}&td3={{ADD SKU}}"/>
```

so,if product is multiple then how i add multiple sku

Comment: This is a question you should ask your pixel tracking manager. This is specific to them about how they will be able to receive multiple values.